# Regex to remove Java comments block containing specific words

Tags: regex, replace, javadoc

I am trying to remove comments containing a specific Java doc comment

Eg. I want to remove this comment block

```
/**
 * @author: Bob
 * @since 28.mar.2008
 *
 */
```

But not this block

```
/** 
 * This class represents ...
 *
 * and so on 
 */
```

So far I have this regexp:

```
^/\*\*(.|\s)+?\*/
```

Which matches a block comment

But I need to some conditionals somewhere in there (eg. block comment that contains "@since"
I guess the key is to use look aheads, but my regex fu is not that good at the moment.

Any one who can help me improve this

Thanks in advance 
Bob

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since Java comments cannot be nested (thanks @Paŭlo), there is a regex for that.

You can do it with:

```
^/\*\*(?=(?:(?!\*/)[\s\S])*?@author: Bob)(?:(?!\*/)[\s\S])*\*/
```

Explanation follows:

```
^               # start-of-string
/\*\*           # literal "/**" (start-of-comment)

(?=             # begin positive look-ahead (...followed by)
  (?:           #   begin non-capturing group
    (?!         #     begin negative look-ahead (...not followed by)
      \*/       #       literal "*/"
    )           #     end negative look-ahead
    [\s\S]      #     anything, including newlines
  )*?           #   end group, repeat non-greedily
  @author: Bob  #   literal "@author: Bob"
)               # end positive look-ahead

                # ... now we have made sure there is "@author: Bob"
                #     before the end of the comment

(?:             # begin non-capturing group
  (?!           #   begin negative look-ahead
    \*/         #     literal "*/"
  )             #   end negative look-ahead
  [\s\S]        #   anything, including newlines (this eats the comment)
)*              # end group, repeat

\*/             # literal "*/" (end-of-comment)
```

Comment: The Java doc comments in the code is not complex and this seemed to work. Thanks

Comment: Huh, from where do you have the "Java comments can be nested"? After `/*` the comment goes to the next `*/`, independently of any `/*` between.

Comment: @Paŭlo: Hm, I expected them to be nestable, so I did a cursory Google search and that seemed to affirm that. I did not try (I'm not really a Java guy). Thanks for the update, I'll change my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you simply switch off the interpreting of `@author` and `@since` by `javadoc`?

There are the `-nosince` option to avoid printing the `@since` block, and `@author` is by default not included (needs the `-author` option).

Of course, if you want to obfuscate that you didn't write the source yourself, remove it from the source. (But make sure this is within the license of the code that you got.)

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the tip, but this problem has nothing to do with the  output to the JavaDoc. The problem was that the source code had a lot of comments with @author: ??? which I wanted to get rid of (without sitting hours doing it manually)