# Removing the comments from a string

Tags: java

I'd like to do a function which gets a string and in case it has inline comments it removes it.

```
public class sample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String code = "/**THIS IS SAMPLE CODE */ public class TestFormatter{public static void main(String[] args){int i =2; String s= \"name\";\\u give give change the values System.out.println(\"Hello World\");//sample}}";

        CodeFormatter codeFormatter = ToolFactory.createCodeFormatter(null);

        TextEdit textEdit = codeFormatter.format(
                CodeFormatter.K_COMPILATION_UNIT, code1, 0, code1.length(), 0,
                null);
        IDocument doc = new Document(code1);
        try {
            textEdit.apply(doc);
            System.out.println(doc.get());
        } catch (MalformedTreeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (BadLocationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting null pointer exception at `textEdit.apply(doc)`. This is because it is not accepting the comments.

Can you tell me what's the best way to remove the comments from the string? (please don't advice too advanced solutions).

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ How is that a duplicate? That's about XML comment. This is about Java inline comment. And also using different library.

Comment: *"I'd like to do a function which gets a string and in case it has inline comments it removes it."* Why would you do that?

Comment: @OP If you use any 3rd party library please say so explicitly with the link to the API.

Comment: @RohitJain I though the same regex.Removed.

Comment: This answer looks helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5433449/regex-to-remove-java-comments-block-containing-specific-words
or this one:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10225923/java-regex-to-remove-sql-comments-from-a-string

Comment: I doubt that a regex is the right tool for this job. I would use a Java scanner, e.g. the one that comes with JavaCC.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
replaceAll("(?s)/\\*.*?\\*/", "")
```

Example:

```
String code = "/**THIS IS SAMPLE CODE */ public class TestFormatter{public static void main(String[] args){int i =2; String s= \"name\";\\\\u give give change the values System.out.println(\"Hello World\");//sample}}";
System.out.println(code.replaceAll("(?s)/\\*.*?\\*/", ""));
```

*Output:*

```
public class TestFormatter{public static void main(String[] args){int i =2; String s= "name";\\u give give change the values System.out.println("Hello World");//sample}}
```

---

**PS.**

if you also want to remove last comments `//sample}}`

Then use `split()`

```
System.out.println(code.replaceAll("(?s)/\\*.*?\\*/", "").split("//")[0]);
// keep in Mind it will also Remove  }} from //sample}}
```

*Output:*

```
 public class TestFormatter{public static void main(String[] args){int i =2; String s= "name";\u give give change the values System.out.println("Hello World");
```

Comment: I am not downvoter but there will be problem with your regex if comments like \*..*\ or \\ will be placed in string. In this cases they are not comments but simple literals and should not be removed. Parsing code is not that easy and probably shouldn't be done with regex...

Comment: @Tarsem: The regex looks same as my answer. When copying the answer at least mention the original author. Btw., I didn't downvote.

Comment: @kadaj Then why was this answered 43 mins ago and yours 24 mins ago - or did it come from another answer?

Comment: @MadProgrammer: look at the edits. Anyway no big deal. My answer came from experimenting at regexpal.com myself.

Answer (score 1):

```
replaceAll("((/\\*)[^/]+(\\*/))|(//.*)", "")
```

This will remove single line, multi-line or doc comments.

The JavaScript compatible regex is `((/\*)[^/]+(\*/))|(//.*)`, which you can try with regexpal.com.

Comment: null pointer exception, actually here the problem is not with the replaceAll method. Iam getting the null pointer exception at textedit.apply(). if the string is not in the proper order then it code will not be formatted into java.