# removing the comments from the string in java

Tags: java

I'd like to do a function which gets a string and in case it has inline comments it removes it.

public class sample {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String code = "/**THIS IS SAMPLE CODE */ public class TestFormatter{public static void main(String[] args){int i =2; String s= \"name\";\\u give give change the values System.out.println(\"Hello World\");//sample}}";

    CodeFormatter codeFormatter = ToolFactory.createCodeFormatter(null);

    TextEdit textEdit = codeFormatter.format(
            CodeFormatter.K_COMPILATION_UNIT, code, 0, code.length(), 0,
            null);
    IDocument doc = new Document(code);
    try {
        textEdit.apply(doc);
        System.out.println(doc.get());
    } catch (MalformedTreeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (BadLocationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}I am getting null pointer exception at textEdit.apply(doc). This is because it is not accepting the comments.

Can you tell me what's the best way to remove the comments from the string? (please don't advice too advanced solutions).

Comment: And what was wrong with the answers from your [last](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18886644/removing-the-comments-from-a-string) question?

Comment: Bet the NPE is from the fact that textEdit is null.

Comment: yes the textedit is null that is the reason i am getting the npe. i have to remove the comments then only the textEdit will have the values. and the string should be in proper order inorder to format it into the java code

Answer (score 1):

try regex

```
    code = code.replaceAll("/\\*\\*.*?\\*/", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?

```
code.replaceAll("(/\\*.*?\\*/)|(//.*?($|\n))", "");
```

- `/\\*.*?\\*/` removes all `/* comment */`
- `//.*?($|\n)` all `// comment`

Comment: sorry it is not working